# Finding the Hamiltonian cycle that uses the least amount of straight lines

Tags: algorithms, graphs, computational-geometry

How can i find the Hamiltonian cycle on an nxn grid that uses the least amount of stright lines (curves left/right as much as possible)?

Here's an example we have devised for 8x8:

[image]

Here is an example we have devised for a 6x6:

[image]

And can this be applied to a grid of any dimensions (apart from non-hamiltonian grids)?

Comment: The problem of minimizing the number of _turns_ in grid-graphs (induced subgraphs of a grid graph) is studied quite a bit, see e.g. [this paper and the references therein](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.04417). It seems that you want to _maximize_ the number of turns, that seems to be less well studied. But maybe similar techniques can be applied, or maybe there's some duality that we can exploit between the problems? (of course, having a full grid is easier than a grid-graph, but this generalization might be interesting to you)

Comment: If you're looking for any solution then this can be easily represented using ILP.

Comment: You're asking about Hamiltonian paths, but there are Hamiltonian **cycles** on both your examples. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @HEKTO yes, a cycle, my bad!

Comment: Imagine an "arrow" starting at some point (e.g., the top-left tile) and travelling (initially down, say) along the path of the cycle. Every quarter-turn tile changes the direction of the arrow by 90 degrees, and the arrow must end up in the same direction as it started when it arrives back in the initial square. Filling a grid with odd cell count using only quarter-turn tiles must result in either strictly more left-turns than right-turns, or vice versa, so an odd-sized grid requires at least some straight-line tiles.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - odd-sized grids aren't Hamiltonian, however yes - it looks like some number of straight-line tiles is necessary even for even-sized grids

Comment: @HEKTO: Ah, so then my observation adds nothing. Well, perhaps a similar but stronger "lower bound" idea can be developed.